# Visualizing FindMarkers result in Seurat using Heatmap

Tags: seurat, heatmap

I used FindMarkers to find the DEGs between two clusters in my dataset using Seurat. I am trying to visualize the outcome using a heatmap but I failed to write the command in R.

```
dput(cluster4_3.markers)
              p_val  avg_logFC pct.1 pct.2    p_val_adj
Vim    1.803527e-44 -1.1689785 0.996 0.999 3.458985e-40
Lgals7 1.479278e-38  1.7615232 0.993 0.552 2.837108e-34
Anxa2  1.797016e-37 -1.3971764 0.629 0.991 3.446497e-33
Tmsb10 6.936830e-31  0.7937881 1.000 1.000 1.330415e-26
Ptma   7.518439e-27  0.5622808 1.000 1.000 1.441961e-22
Jund   2.044576e-25 -0.9881766 0.993 0.999 3.921293e-21
```

When I tried:

```
DoHeatmap(cluster4_3.markers, features = NULL) + 
scale_fill_gradientn(colors = rev(RColorBrewer::brewer.pal(n = 7, name = "RdYlBu")))
Error in UseMethod(generic = "DefaultAssay", object = object) : 
  no applicable method for 'DefaultAssay' applied to an object of class "data.frame"
```

It didn't work. I was trying to replicate this command:

```
top10 <- pbmc.markers %>% group_by(cluster) %>% top_n(n = 10, wt = avg_logFC)
DoHeatmap(pbmc, features = top10$gene) + NoLegend() + 
  scale_fill_gradientn(colors = rev(RColorBrewer::brewer.pal(n = 7, name = "RdYlBu")))
```

I tried to extract some info from the csv file but I couldn't determine which parameter is important (p_val avg_logFC   pct.1   pct.2   p_val_adj). Also, I didn't know which parameter to use to use the group_by function. That's one of my attempts:

```
clus4vs3 <- cluster4_3.markers$p_val %>% 
    group_by(pct.1) %>% 
    top_n(n = 10, wt = avg_logFC)
Error in UseMethod("group_by_") :
  no applicable method for 'group_by_' applied to an object of class "c('double', 'numeric')"
```

Now that I understand 'group_by' only accepts a categorical variable, how can I write a command that displays the top20 differentially expressed genes between cluster 4 and 3 in a heatmap ?

Comment: Please a) include a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) of your data, (i.e. by using ``dput(cluster4_3.markers)`` b) tell us what didn't work because it's not 'obvious' to us since we can't see your data. Include details of all error messages. We can't help you otherwise.

Comment: @user438383 Sorry for the ambiguity. I just attached the result of dput(cluster4_3.markers).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `DoHeatmap()` call, you do not provide features so the function does not know which genes/features to use for the heatmap.

In your last function call, you are trying to group based on a continuous variable `pct.1` whereas `group_by` expects a categorical variable.

Comment: I understand a little bit more now. I just want to show the DEGs expressed in both clusters in 1 heatmap. But I failed (still failing) to write the command logically.

Comment: I am having a hard time understanding "DEGs expressed in both clusters", by definition a DEG is expressed in one of the clusters, not both. You can feed `rownames(cluster4_3.markers)` to the `features` variable of `DoHeatmap()`.

Comment: What I mean is to compare the DEGs expressed between those two clusters. Does that make sense?

Comment: ```
> DoHeatmap(cluster4_3.markers, features = rownames(cluster4_3.markers)) + 
+   scale_fill_gradientn(colors = rev(RColorBrewer::brewer.pal(n = 7, name = "RdYlBu")))
Error in UseMethod(generic = "DefaultAssay", object = object) : 
  no applicable method for 'DefaultAssay' applied to an object of class "data.frame"

Comment: `DoHeatmap()` takes a `Seurat` object as a first argument. Please go through the documentation and vignettes.

Comment: Thank you for bearing with me.
I edited the command using the only seurat object I've created with the main set of data:
``` 
> DoHeatmap(tg14, features = rownames(cluster4_3.markers)) + 
+   scale_fill_gradientn(colors = rev(RColorBrewer::brewer.pal(n = 7, name = "RdYlBu")))
Error: cannot allocate vector of size 580.8 Mb
```
I am currently looking through the vignettes but if you can still give me more clues, that'll be great!

Comment: Thanks a lot for helping. This fixed my problem: 
```
top10 <- cluster4_3.markers %>% top_n(n = 10, wt = avg_logFC)
DoHeatmap(tg14, features = top10$gene) + NoLegend() + 
  scale_fill_gradientn(colors = rev(RColorBrewer::brewer.pal(n = 7, name = "RdYlBu")))